How do I customize "Open Files" context menu in Side Bar in Sublime Text?
Recently, after gaining the know-how of customizing the Context menu of Side Bar (Files & Folders(Project Folders)), I just had question sprung in my mind, how do I go about adding custom menu item of my own to Sublime Text Open Files > items' Context menu ?
Customizing the Side Bar is easy but how do I target the specific Open Files context menu and not touch other Side Bar elements at all ?
As I afore-mentioned, I now know that you can add items to Side Bar with below:
[
    { "command": "my_command_1", "caption": "My Command 1", "id": "my_command_uniq" },
    ....
    ....
]

But how do I add custom new menu items to "Open Files" items' context menu ? Any ideas ??
